# What do you call this type of analysis?

Tags: self-study

I do a lot of statistical analysis at my job but I'm unsure of the terminology for what I do.

I work for a lab where we screen every newborn in the state for 29 genetic disorders. That's 100,000 newborns a year, and sometimes we screen certain babies twice so about 125,000 samples total. I'm constantly taking the data from our information management system and answering questions such as, "How many babies were born at <2500 grams? Of those babies, how many had a positive screening for X disorder? Of this group, how many were actually diagnosed with the disorder?"

Sometimes, I'm looking at the data to answer questions about compliance to our rules. Such as, "How many hospitals submitted samples which were contaminated?" Other times, I am literally looking at the data just to see what kind of patterns or anomalies exist.

I use excel for all of my analyses and, again, all of the data comes from our information management system.

I didn't intend on going down this path in my career (my degree is in Biology) but management has been very pleased with my work, so it is the majority of what I do now. I also really enjoy it, and would like to be able to add this work to my resume and hopefully find a similar job. I just need to be able to properly articulate it.

Comment: Neonatal data analysis?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your answer, you are performing **Descriptive statistics** as well as **Exploratory data analysis**.

The following is the exploratory analysis part.

> I am literally looking at the data just to see what kind of patterns
>   or anomalies exist

This is the descriptive statistics part.

> How many babies were born at <2500 grams? Of those babies, how many
>   had a positive screening for X disorder?

Descriptive stats is all about extracting information from data, whereas exploratory data analysis is all about exploring the data through plots for patterns and doing anomaly detection through techniques like outlier analysis, etc.

And as @EdM nicely put, the title you can put on your resume can be **data analyst**, which is a domain-independent title.

---

So, you can articulate it as follows:

Done descriptive statistical analysis on the ___________ data where the ______ data is analyzed ........  <-- `analyzed` should be followed by the analyses and conclusions you have derived.

The exploratory analysis part can also be articulated in a similar way as of above.

Comment: A title like "data analyst" would cover both these tasks, which you summarized nicely, and be simple to put on a resume.

Comment: Yeah, a data analyst must fit in nicely.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are just performing basic descriptive statistics. If you wanted to determine whether your results are statistically significant you have a couple options. 1) You could probably run a chi-square goodness of fit test. This will answer the question, "Are the number of  babies were born at <2500 grams significantly different than the number of babies born at >2500 grams?" 2) Otherwise, if you have population statistics (i.e. I expect 10% of babies to be born <2500 grams) you could run a one-sample t-test to check if the numbers you are seeing are significantly different than what you would expect to see in the population.